# How to load .sks files from a Swift Playground that is embedded in a workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, swift-playground

In the documentation for fileNamed: when loading scenes from .sks files says:

```
The name of the file, without a file extension.
The file must be in the app’s main bundle and have a .sks filename extension.
```

My usage in a Playground:

```
if let scene = PlanetsScene(fileNamed: "PlanetsScene")
```

Is there any workaround for this? Stuff that runs in Playground do not seem to have access to the apps main bundle. I have embedded my Playground inside the project workspace, and can access all the other classes i set public, but can't just seem to load `.sks` files.

Comment: If you are using Xcode 9, creating a new Playground project and selecting Game as the template will generate code that uses a .sks file.

Comment: Yeah, but that can't use the actual .sks files in my project, which is what i want. I don't want to duplicate all my sks files..

Comment: If you are using a playground inside your workspace alongside your project than you must turn that code in to a dynamic framework. Than you can import that inside your app and your playground. You just add any assets to the framework bundle.

Check this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrdxSNG-_DE

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-playgrounds-to-xcode-projects/

Comment: Yeah it is a framework, problem is that the method does not allow specification of bundle, i have the assets as a member of the framework target.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put symbolic links to the original `*.sks` files into your Playground's `Resources`?

Comment: Gave you gotten that to work? Does not seem to work when i tried